# Last image out of boundary in bootstrap album

Tags: css, image-gallery, bootstrap-4

I have used the **bootstrap album** as a starting point to create an album.
The problem is that **last image in each row is larger than the first two.**
I have checked the css code but unable to identify the issue.

Here is the link to my page

brotherxii.com/aquariangallery.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this on your CSS

```
   .card > a > img{
    max-width: 100%
    }
```

Comment: No problem.. :)